# Rewiring an antique lamp

Tags: electrical

I am rewiring an antique reading lamp with SPT-1 wire (wire is interior thru an small opening ~1/4 inch).  Can I use with a 3-way switch and bulb?

Comment: it's hard to find 3-way bulbs anymore, might consider a dimmer...

Comment: No problem finding 3 way bulbs - including LEDs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [tri-light controls](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-way_lamp) normally happen via a switch that is right at the lamp socket. As such, you use a special socket and don't wire them any differently than a normal socket.

Answer (score 1):

A 3-way bulb switch (i.e., 2 connections on bulb with result of A, B, A+B) requires an extra wire between the socket (which is also different from a regular socket) and the switch.

However, if the switch and socket are one assembly, [like in this kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002DNIBEY) then that is not an issue. I am not endorsing this kit (first one I found) but something like that may be the easiest way to do this - use whatever parts you need and toss the rest.

In general, if you can make everything fit then you should be OK. But watch out for sharp edges that can cut into insulated wire and make sure you have enough clearance for safety around the bulb - even LED bulbs can get hot in spots, despite using less power and generating less heat than traditional incandescent bulbs.